# String subscript out of range. I dont know how to index array with char, so i ussed (unsigned int), but it didnt worked

Tags: c++, algorithm

This is my code that i used to make an array that i tried to index with characters, but it returns me an error String subscript out of range.

```
#define ALPHA (256)
#define MAX_PATLEN (100)

int betap[ MAX_PATLEN+1 ];
int Delta[ ALPHA ];

void makeDelta(std::string p, int m ) {
int i;
for( i = 0; i < ALPHA; ++i )
Delta[i] = m + 1;
for( i = 0; i < m; ++i )
Delta[(unsigned int) p[i] ] = m - i; 
}
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do?

Comment: What if the length of the string `p` is less than `m - 1`?

Comment: i made it that int m=p.size()

Comment: its used for shifts in pattern matching algorithm

Comment: @kycork Please produce an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Please run in a debugger, and when the crash happens you can go to the location *in your code* of the crash and examine the values of variables.

Comment: well when it crashes it says  Debug assertion failed!  File c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring  Line: 1440  Expression: string subscript out of range

Comment: @kycork that indicates that `m > p.size()`, so the last loop will read off the end of `p`. Your function should check for this condition.

Comment: Not related to your error, but change `unsigned int` to `unsigned char`. Otherwise negative character values will cause out of bounds access on `Delta` .

Answer (score 0):

String subscript out of range indicate that something in [] is out of range. Here maybe p[m] is not defined. I mean length of string p is less than m.

Comment: if it helps, in an implementation from 2007 uses CTYPE* p and not std:string p

Comment: I guess the issue is with casting.. Try using p[i]-'0' instead of (unsigned int) p[i] . Or try using atoi(p[i]). Hope this helps..

Comment: does atoi() need any specific library